# heroku re-orders ruby on rails loop output of partials

Tags: ruby, loops, heroku, naming-conventions

I have a page which renders several partials; on my local mac everything is fine but after I push to heroku and visit the page the order of the partials is different!

I render partials with the code below and thought I controlled the order with a file naming convention.

html.erb:

```
<% Dir["app/views/partials/ws/*.html.erb"].each do |ws| %>
<%= render 'partials/ws/' + File.basename(ws,'.html.erb').slice(1..-1) %>
<% end %>
```

The partials use a naming convention:

```
_ws_01-why.html.erb
_ws_02-what.html.erb
_ws_03-who.html.erb
_ws_04-where.html.erb
_ws_05-when1.html.erb
_ws_06-how.html.erb
```

Heroku renders in this order:

```
_ws_01-why.html.erb
_ws_02-what.html.erb
_ws_06-how.html.erb
_ws_04-where.html.erb
_ws_05-when1.html.erb
_ws_03-who.html.erb
```

I'm not sure how heroku is interpreting the naming convention / ruby loop order... Wondering if there is a better naming convection or logic to add in my loop to control the order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<% Dir["app/views/partials/ws/*.html.erb"].each do |ws| %>
```

to this:

```
<% Dir["app/views/partials/ws/*.html.erb"].sort.each do |ws| %>
```

You cannot be sure than an enumerator will choose the same order in all cases unless you force it somehow.

Comment: That the reason for the different ordering is due to the file system does not make what I said invalid - if you want to ensure ordering when using enumerators then you have to force the order. The same principle applies with say, a database that has different ordering due to a different collation on the production server, you should force the ordering when you want a specific ordering, the collation is in fact irrelevant, as is the file system here.

Comment: lains reasoning and solution is solid! Thank you lain